# A lot of confusion in this question of finding purely real values of theta?

Tags: complex-numbers

[image]

For purely imaginary , it should have been
$\dfrac{8i\sin\theta}{1+4\sin^2\theta}$

Why written $3-4\sin^2\theta$.

Also , I read that the range of theta has to be between $-\pi$ and $\pi$. Why written $n\pi$ here?

I couldn’t find the homework question tag so posted it here. Please help in understanding where am I wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for purely imaginary, $z=\dfrac{8\sin \theta}{1+4\sin^2\theta}$, but for that to happen, it's real part must be $0$, shouldn't it? and that's why the real part that is,  $\Re(z)=\dfrac{3-4\sin^2\theta}{1+4\sin^2\theta}=0$.

As for, the $n\pi$ part, $\theta$ can take infinite values as $\sin \theta$ is defined for all $\theta$, (yes, even complex values too! but that is not relevant here), so the general value of $\theta$ that satisfies the final equation is $\theta=n\pi \pm \dfrac{\pi}3$, you can put it back in the equation and verify that it satisfies the equation or not.

Comment: Why is it npi +- pi/3.Why not simply +-pi/3?

Comment: Ok.Thank you sir.

Comment: You might google general solution of trigonometric equations, that might help you. As an example, if $\sin x=0$, we write $x=n\pi$, where $n$ is any integer, and not just $x=0$ because that is just one solution...we want to write all.

Comment: Ok,So it is like sin 30 and sin 210 have same values.

Comment: No, $\sin(30^{\circ})=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sin(210^{\circ})=-\frac{1}{2}$. But $\sin(30^{\circ})=\sin(150^{\circ})=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Ok.Got it now.zthanks

Answer (score 1):

The complex number $a+b i$ [where $a,b$ are real numbers] is purely imaginary iff $a=0.$ So write your number in $a+b i$ form and see that $a$ has numerator $3-4 \sin^2 \theta$ and a strictly positive denominator.

Comment: Thank you sir ..

Comment: @user282657 You're welcome.